# Instagram Graph API - Get all media / skip the first ones

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I used the following site to fetch the media from a specific Instagram user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery

It is working properly, but the problem is, that i want to get more media of this user. The API just gives me the last 25 posts this user uploaded.
Is there any option to get all media or the option to skip these 25 posts and get the next 25?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If that endpoint supports pagination, then this should work the same way as for regular Graph API requests, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for that comment. You are right, that is the way to go, thank you very much!